# c# Inconsistent Accessibility Prevents Private Classes as parameters for Protected Methods

Tags: c#, namespaces

Here is a simplified example of how I want my code to work.  Please note that this code will not compile:

```
namespace SpecificNamespace
{
    class UtilityObject
    {
        //properties
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        protected void doStuff(UtilityObject utilityObject)
        {
            //does stuff
        }
    }

    // include implementations of Entity
}

namespace GeneralNamespace
{
    public static class World
    {
        public static List<SpecificNamespace.Entity> Entities = new List<SpecificNamespace.Entity>();
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile because of the line:

```
protected void doStuff(UtilityObject utilityObject)
```

> Inconsistent accessibility: Parameter type 'UtilityObject' is less accessable than method 'Entity.doStuff(UtilityObject utilityObject)'

But I swear, I was only going to implement `Entity` for classes that are declared inside of `SpecificNamespace` and therefore any class that has reference to the protected method `Entity.Dostuff` would also have access to `UtillityObject`. Since no class outside of this namespace has any business knowing what a `UtilityObject` is, I do not want to declare it a public. On the otherhand `Entity` needs to be public so that the Entities can be referred to generically.

Is there a way around this?  Is this a shortfall of the C# conventions?  Am I just being too precious about this?

Comment: Side note: I'm quite sure you have wrong idea about namespaces - namespaces in C# mean absolutely nothing to visibility. They are just part of type name. You can declare all your classes in `System` namespace - but it not going to give them any magic powers because of that.

Comment: so making a class public does not make it visible outside of it's namespace?

Comment: If only you are going to call it in your own assembly you could make `doStuff` internal instead of protected. That would resolve the error.

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry no, other way around - changing namespaces don't impact visibility. If it is public every other type will see it irrespective of namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make UtilityObject an inner class inside Entity with protected accessebility level.

Comment: Short and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you moved UtilityObject into the base class Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    class UtilityObject
    {
        //properties
    }
```

That is a step closer; however, UtilityObject has to be at least protected scope or better, because think of it this way: if `public class A : Entity` is defined, class `A` needs to be able to see UtilityObject, and it can't if it's private (even private within the class).  You **may** be able to use `protected class UtilityObject` with nested classes but not sure; if you can, that would be closer....

But that is the essence of why you are getting that error; all future implementations need to be able to add it because of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a public interface `IUtilityObject` and then you can keep your UtilityObject class internal like you have it:

```
namespace SpecificNamespace
{
    public interface IUtilityObject
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class UtilityObject : IUtilityObject
    {
        //properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        protected void doStuff(IUtilityObject utilityObject)
        {
            //does stuff
        }
    }

    // include implementations of Entity
}
```

Comment: or I could make Entity private and make it implement a public Interface.

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry I don't think you can make Entity private where it currently stands. You can only make a class private if it's nested in a more visible class.

Comment: oh, so what does making a class 'public' do if it's not nested?